# Windows 8 on Hyper-V (2008R2/2012) with Remote-FX?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Where can I found  the driver ?
The integration services disk (vmguest.iso) not support Windows 8,
but there are two unknown devices on devices manager, and only Microsoft Basic Display Adapter....

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I found the driver ?

What driver?

> The integration services disk (vmguest.iso) not support Windows 8,

We,, 2008R2 has no proper RemoteFx anyway. But the baseline here is - why do you have the delusion you need to install a driver? Since Windows 7 Windows comes iwth the most current version of theintegration services. Just install windows 8, the drivers are part of it - the new ones for Server 2012.

> but there are two unknown devices on devices manager, and only Microsoft Basic Display 
>   Adapter..

Smelly. You talk of RTM version Server 2012 and RTM version windows I would stay away from Server 2008 on this point - the new 2012 has  lot better RemoteFx support. Install server, install graphics card driver on server, install client and you hsould have the lclient at leat not showing unknown drivers.

I am just looking on m main work VM  and I see a "Microsoft Hyper-V Video" adapter installed. This is baseline - pur Windows 8, pathced up from Windows update, NO driver install, running on a Server 2012.

Comment: I'm using Server 2008R2, and run Windows 8 on Hyper-V.
But there were problem with driver...so I delusion I need to install a driver for it....lol

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 pro doesnot come with remotefx drivers as Enterprise version is only remotefx supported version. So you will see 2 unknown devices in device manager.